# I can't match using ansible lineinfile regex with two fields and a dollar sign beginning second field

Tags: regex, ansible

Data:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

Ansible snippet:

```
- name: Add domain name
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/postfix/main.cf
    regexp: '^(mydestination =) ($myhostname.+)$'
    line: '\1 jlhimpel.net, \2'
    backrefs: true
```

Expected results:

```
mydestination = jlhimpel.net, $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

Actual results: No match found

Other tries: I have tried \$ and \\$ to escape the first dollar sign

Ansible version: 2.9.18

Comment: You do not have any `=` in the data. Try removing `=`, `'^(mydestination) (\$myhostname.+)$'`

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the Data:

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the Data:  s/b mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost

Comment: Did you try `'\\1 jlhimpel.net, \\2'`?

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the data then.

Comment: @zeitounator I edited the input to show the correct input data.

Comment: @Stribizew I tried '\\1 jlhimpel.net, \\2' and it also did not make the match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```yaml
  - name: Add domain name
    ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/postfix/main.cf
      regexp: '^\s*mydestination\s*=\s*(.*)(\$myhostname.*)$'
      line: 'mydestination = jlhimpel.net, \2'
      backrefs: true
```

Quoting from module [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#ansible-builtin-lineinfile-manage-lines-in-text-files) attribute [regexp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-regexp)

> *"When modifying a line the regexp should typically match both the initial state of the line as well as its state after replacement by line to ensure idempotence."*

Comment: The \s* clue put me onto the correct answer.  It turns out the original file had two spaces after the equals sign and I was matching on only one.  Thanks Vladimir.